# How can I get the background color of one HTML/ASP row to change when a boolean is set true?

Tags: html, asp-classic, vbscript

I've got a table generate on page-load that is full of data.  When the user clicks an ID, that row needs to highlight.  Right now, I've got it so that when the user clicks the ID, a boolean is set true, and then some other stuff happens.  I have it set so that when the boolean is true, that row will be highlighted.  However, this isn't happening.  Can you help me figure out why?

```
<%  
    If RS.RecordCount > 0 then 
        Do While Not RS.EOF
            if RS("ROLL_ID") = IntRollID then
                boolDetailTable = true
            end if
%>              
<TR <% if boolDetailTable = true then %> bgcolor "#CCFF00" <%end if%>>
    <a target=_top href="<% = getInfo(RS("ROLL_ID"))%>" onMouseOver="window.status='Click to get info';return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';return true;">
    <TD style="width: 9%; cursor: hand; border-right: none; align: center; vertical-align: center;" 
        title="Click to get info">
        <font color="navy"><%= RS("ROLL_ID")%></font>
    </TH>
    </a>
    <TD style="width=25%"  style="font-size: 12pt" align="center">&nbsp; <% = RS("ROLL_FINISH_DESC") %></TD>
    <TD style="width=20%" style="font-size: 12pt" align="center">&nbsp; <% = RS("ROLL_DIAMETER") %></TD>
    <TD style="width=20%" style="font-size: 12pt" align="center">&nbsp; <% = RS("ROLL_CROWN") %></TD>
    <TD style="width=10%" style="font-size: 12pt" align="center">&nbsp; <% = RS("ROLL_LOCKOUT_YN") %></TD>
</TR>
<%

        RS.MoveNext()
        Loop        
    end if
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you need to change one of your tags in the code below - you need to start with either the `<th>` or end with the `</td>` as you have a mismatch.

For this example I changed `</TH>` to `</TD>`

You will also notice I added an `onClick(this.parent);` to the `<td>`

```
<TD onClick="SetColor(this.parent);" style="width: 9%; cursor: hand; border-right: none; align: center; vertical-align: center;" 
    title="Click to get info">
    <font color="navy"><%= RS("ROLL_ID")%></font>
</TD>
```

The `OnClick` will send the elements parent - in this case the row itself (`<tr>`) to a function called `SetColor(elem)`

Have a javascript function like this in your page:

```
function SetColor(elem){
      elem.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
}
```

This should change the row to a red color for you.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the suggestions.

Second, I took the new <TD> you wrote and replaced mine, and then I copied the javascript function into my page.

However, I'll admit I've never actually put javascript into an asp document before, I'm not entirely sure where I'm supposed to put it or what tags I put around it.  I'm much more of a console programmer.  Web development is completely new to me.

Answer (score 1):

try the .css if you have a

```
tr.active{color:#CCFF00;}
```

Comment: My app actually doesn't have any CSS right now.  Is there any way I can do that without it?